# Aptana Studio 3 Blank Terminal

Tags: windows, aptana3

I'm was using Aptana studio 3 specifically for ruby on rails for about 2 months on windows 8.1, Now I've installed fresh windows 8.1 and did a clean windows install, and installed Aptana Studio 3 again but now when I open it the Terminal is not working at all, it is blank and I'm unable to type anything in terminal.

There was another user "Hung ta" at stackoverflow who was having the same issue as mine, but he solved it by going into Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git. At Git Executable he gave path to git.

I've tried that too but still the terminal is not working. I've searched for solution on Google but found nothing there too.

I already have java installed, Git was also installed with aptana studio.
Kindly let me know if there is any solution to this problem, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with the Aptana plugin on Eclipse IDE and solved it by updating my MinGW/MSYS (providing the bourne shell on Aptana) installation.